# Share a common observable collection for both list and grid layout in long list selector?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a list of items that are displayed in portrait orientation in a wp8 app. I have defined GroupHeaderTemplate and JumpListStyle, so it neatly shows as a grouped list. I created a KeyedList class that represents a list grouped by a key and my ViewModel exposes ObservableCollection of KeyedList.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Timbre.Collections
{
    public class KeyedList<TKey, TItem> : List<TItem>
    {
        public TKey Key
        {
            get;
            protected set;
        }

        public KeyedList(TKey key)
            : base()
        {
            Key = key;
        }

        public KeyedList(TKey key, IEnumerable<TItem> items)
            : base(items)
        {
            Key = key;
        }

        public KeyedList(IGrouping<TKey, TItem> grouping) :
            base(grouping)
        {

            Key = grouping.Key;
        }
    }
}
```

The Property in the ViewModel is as follows:

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyedList<string, Album>> Albums
    {
        get { return this.groupedAlbums; }
        private set
        {
            if (this.groupedAlbums == value) return;
            this.groupedAlbums = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Albums);
        }
    }
```

The LongListSelector binds to this ObservableCollection and works properly. 
Now when the orientation of the page changes to landscape, I want to change the layout mode from List to Grid on the LongListSelection and I want to get rid of the grouping as it takes quite some space and I just want to display a grid of pictures. 
Typically I would set this on the long list when orientation changes to landscape: 
    IsGroupingEnabled=false

But I'm no longer able to bind to the same ObservableCollection I used before, as it exposes a list of lists and not a simple list. Now I know this can be solved by exposing 2 ObservableCollections in the ViewModel, one for grouped list and one for simple list. But typically, I want to show the same item that was visible to the user in the flat list when the layout mode changes to grid. Is there some way to just expose one ObservableCollection and yet just change the LayoutMode from List to Grid and make it work?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to resolve the issue by setting the GroupHeaderTemplate to null in Landscape Orientation

Comment: I thought the issue was fixed but apparently its not the case. The items still do not show as one set. Its just that the group headers are not displayed, but they are still displayed in groups. Is there a solution for this?